# What's the referent of this 'which'?

Tags: relative-pronouns

I think the part after the 'which' in boldface is already a complete sentence. What does it refer to?

> She is held fast by the corporeal, **which** the continual association and constant care of the body have wrought into her nature.
>
> -- Plato's [Phaedo](http://oll.libertyfund.org/?option=com_staticxt&staticfile=show.php?title=766&chapter=93700&layout=html&Itemid=27) 81

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relative pronoun *which* is understood as the object of *wrought*.  It refers to "the corporeal".
We can understand your sentence as a combination of two smaller sentences:

> She is held fast by **the corporeal**.  The continual association and constant care of the body have wrought **the corporeal** into her nature.

To put them together, we replace the second instance of "the corporeal" with the relative pronoun *which*.  Because we have to move *which* to the front of the relative clause, it leaves behind a gap:

```
 [ which [ association and care ] have wrought _____gap into her nature ]
       ↖_________________________________________↙
```

When we read this sentence, we understand *which* as the object of *wrought*, even though it doesn't appear in object position.  In syntactic terms, we can say that the gap is the object, and *which* and the gap refer to the same thing; they both refer to "the corporeal".